# Syncing icons between front and back end

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i am building a notification system where i have little icons under primary image (like on facebook, where icon indicates if notification is about post react, comment or anything else), now i am planning to send string like "purchase" | "greeting" and etc. and convert them to icons on frontend. but problem here is that i have to keep separate data on both side, one on server which lists possible icon types and one on frontend which keeps track of which icon type is compatible to which icon, and they have to be in sync, which is a problem for me because i want it to be automated, while i could send icon (react-icons) to frontend from backend i think that would affect bandwidth terribly, so what is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: Hey, have you considered storing all possible react-icons on the front end and sending a string ID like "purchase" that lets the client choose the right icon?

Comment: yes but what if i want to add another string id?

Comment: Well, the client-side bundle has to comprise all icons that the server might want to ask to show. If a new icon appears, the client-side bundle needs to recompile so if the server sends the icon ID the client knows how to show it.

Comment: If you had client- and server-side code in JavaScript (Node.js on the server-side) you could keep them in sync in the build time by having some kind of a linter that says "the server-side list got a new icon to show, make sure you client-side bundle is adjusted accordingly".

Comment: I would imagine a TypeScript enum as the list of icon IDs that both the client and the server bundles use, so you can make sure two bundles are in sync, if not - TypeScript won't compile.